# Can I assign a value to an entire class in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I am writing my own operating system in C++, the problem though is that the regular `string.h` file doesn't work properly, so I need to create my own string class (which I want to do anyway - `string.h` working or not) but I am having trouble figuring out how to write it so I can use it in the following way:

```
string a = "Hello";
int i = a.length();
```

or even

```
int i = a.length;
```

Currently my string.h looks kind of like this:

```
typedef char *string;
class String {     //same name of typedef and class means compilation error
    char *value;
    int length(string value);
```

But using that implementation it would have to be used like:

```
String a = new String;
a.value = "Hello World";
```

I am sorry if this is the wrong website for such "theoretical" questions, but please direct me to another more suitable place for this question if this is the case.

Comment: Did you try writing so? If yes, what specific trouble are you facing with?

Comment: `string a = "Hello";` is unrelated to the header `string.h`. `string.h` is a C header for C strings. The C++ version for C strings is `cstring`. `std::string` is declared in `string`.

Comment: Don't use "string.h" its C not C++. You need to use <string> and `std::string`.

Comment: Are you asking about [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)? Btw you should really learn C++ deeply before even starting to write an operating system. You may for example learn that there are literally thousands things more interesting to do.

Comment: Your code works for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/C58WwiUnGcAgE8YQ

Comment: @jabaa `string` is not `std::string`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I wrote my comment before the edit. But my comment is still true. OP's `string` is unrelated to `string.h` (if it's the standard `string.h`).

Comment: Did you read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) - on paper?

Comment: @jabaa original post: "so I need to create my own string class". Yes, probably they should be using `std::string` and call it a day, but lets not confuse them when thats not what they ask for

Comment: It looks like you have lots of misconceptions about what classes/structs/methods are in C++, I'm unsure how to answer your question as it is right now. Please consider reading a good book or taking a course in C++ which covers the basics.

Comment: You shouldn't create a class `string` or a file `string.h` to avoid confusion. Both already exist.

Comment: `String a = new String;` is wrong unless a constructor like `String(String* s)` is defined. `a.value = "Hello World";` is wrong because a string literal (converted to `const char*`) is assigned to `char*` variable.

Comment: @jabaa sorry, me again. The class that exists is called `std::string`. Its completely fine to declare a `string` in a different namespace, thats what namespaces are good for (introducing all names from `std` via a using is to be blamed for potiential confusion)

Comment: You may be interested in [Haiku](https://www.haiku-os.org/), which is an open source operating system written in C++.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 It's not wrong but a line like `string a = "Hello";` will cause confusion if you don't tell that this is a user defined type.

Comment: @jabaa depends on how much you are used to `using ...`. I am used to code where `string` and  `std::string` are not the same.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, in my teams `using namespace std;` is not allowed an I know that `string` and `std::string` are probably not the same but on Stackoverflow `string` is almost always `std::string` especially for beginners. I remember my first year of C++. My teacher taught me that `using namespace std;` is a necessary line without explanation.

Comment: @jabaa you cannot blame OP for not following bad practice ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time we use the standard library string implementation. That can be included with the following line:

```
#include <string>
```

And then use it in the following fashion:

```
std::string who = "me"; 
int len = who.size();
```

But since you are learning, you seem passionate about implementing your own string implementation. Which is a very good practice. So I quickly grabbed a header file for string implementation online:

mystring.h

```
class mystring
{
    char *pcString; // pointer to a char array
    int iCapacity; // capacity; strings grow
public: // note the public here
    // some constructors
    mystring(void);
    mystring(int);
    mystring(const char*);
    mystring(const string&);
    // some ops
    mystring& string::operator=(const string &strInstance);
    mystring& string::operator+(const string &strInstance);
    // your custom length
    int length() const; 
};
```

Extra: Code review stack exchange [stdstring-implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98329/stdstring-implementation)

Comment: there are some typos, none of them are constructors for mystring class

Comment: Also, [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Five, actually.

Comment: @Alessandro Teruzzi yes bad copy pasta

Answer (score 0):

> ```cpp
> string a = "Hello";
> ```

That will not work in C++11 and later, because you have declared `string` as a `typedef` for a non-const `char*` pointer, but the string literal `"Hello"` is a `const char[6]` that *decays* into a `const char*` pointer.  You can't assign a `const char*` to a non-const `char*`.

However, prior to C++11, you could assign a string literal to a non-const `char*` pointer, but that practice was discouraged as it promoted the possibility of modifying read-only data.  Which is why it is no longer allowed in C++11 and later.

You likely meant to use your `String` class instead:

```cpp
String a = "Hello";
```

But that will not work either, because your `String` class lacks a constructor that accepts a `const char*` as input.

> ```cpp
> int i = a.length();
> int i = a.length;
> ```

Neither of those will work, because `a` is declared as a `char*` pointer, so it has no methods or data members.  But, even if you had used your `String` class instead, `a.length()` would still not work because `length()` is implicitly `private` and it takes a `char*` as input, which you are not passing in.

> ```cpp
> typedef char *string;
> class String {     //same name of typedef and class means compilation error
> ```

They don't have the same name.  C++ is case-sensitive, so `string` and `String` are different names.

> But using that implementation it would have to be used like:
>
> ```cpp
> String a = new String;
> a.value = "Hello World";
> ```

Wrong.  If implemented *properly*, it can be used like this:

```cpp
String a = "Hello World";
```

In order for that to work, your `String` class would need to look more like this:

```cpp
class String {
private:
    char *value;

public:
    String(const char* str);
    ~String();
    int length() const;
};
```

And then you can implement it like this:

```cpp
#include <cstring>

String::String(const char* str)
    : value(NULL)
{
    if (str) {
        value = new char[std::strlen(str) + 1];
        std::strcpy(value, str);
    }
}

String::~String()
{
    delete[] value;
}

int String::length() const
{
    return (value) ? std::strlen(value) : 0;
}
```

Now this will work, as expected:

```cpp
String a = "Hello";
int i = a.length();
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/VCiecP)

Obviously, this is just an example, there are better ways to implement this.  Like caching the length value in a data member.  And implementing a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator, and a move constructor and a move assignment operator, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Now, that being said, C++ already has a standard [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class that handles all of these details for you.  Implementing a custom `String` class is fine as an exercise in learning how to implement classes, but in real production code, use `std::string` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string a = "Hello";
size_t i = a.length(); // or a.size()
```